# Pandas date_range: drop nanoseconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to create the following date range series with quarterly frequency:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.date_range(start = "1980", periods = 5, freq = 'Q-Dec')
```

Which returns

```
DatetimeIndex(['1980-03-31', '1980-06-30', '1980-09-30', '1980-12-31',
              '1981-03-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

However, when I output this object to CSV I see the time portion of the series. e.g.

```
1980-03-31 00:00:00, 1980-06-30 00:00:00
```

Any idea how I can get rid of the time portion so when I export to a csv it just shows:

```
1980-03-31, 1980-06-30
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing nano-seconds, you are just seeing the `time` portion of the `datetime` that `pandas` has created for the `DatetimeIndex`.  You can extract only the `date` portion with `.date()`.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
dr = pd.date_range(start="1980", periods=5, freq='Q-Dec')

print(dr[0].date())
```

**Results:**

```
1980-03-31
```

Comment: Either way, I was hoping to get rid of the time portion for the whole series so it doesn't show when I export to a CSV. I've edited my question.

Comment: @measure_theory, show some example code of how you actually export to csv.  If you need to retain the DatetimeIndex, then you cannot get rid of the time. But it might be easy enough to store in csv without time.

Comment: well, I would generally just do pd.to_csv(file). I do need to retain the Datetime index.

Comment: @measure_theory, It is the *just generally* that is the problem.  pandas and DatetimeIndex do not have a `to_csv`.  Series and DataFrames have `to_csv`.  So what are you using, and how are you using it?  We can play the  I answer, you change the question game for much longer than I would want to.

Comment: The series is either an index or a column in a pandas DataFrame object. So df.to_csv(out), where df is the DataFrame containing the series constructed with pd.date_range()